# HTTPS issue with createSocket, connect and connectionTimeout

Tags: java, ssl, https

When I create a SSL socket like this:

```
sslSocket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
```

everything works. `socketFactory` is a `SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()`. However, I want to set connection timeout. Therefore, I have changed above line to this code:

```
sslSocket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket();
sslSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), connectionTimeout);
```

but then I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" jodd.http.HttpException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target;
```

cause exception:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

When I debug this, I've noticed that in the first case, the code get all valid certificates from the requested site. In the second case, these certificates were missing, hence the error.

What else I need to add in my 2-liner change, to make it work like the first one-liner version?

COMPLETE STACKTRACE

```
jodd.http.HttpException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; <--- sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at jodd.http.HttpRequest.open(HttpRequest.java:667)
    at jodd.http.HttpRequest.open(HttpRequest.java:649)
    at jodd.http.HttpRequest._send(HttpRequest.java:747)
    at jodd.http.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:742)
    at jodd.JoddHttpTest.main(JoddHttpTest.java:56)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at jodd.http.net.SocketHttpConnectionProvider.createSSLSocket(SocketHttpConnectionProvider.java:153)
    at jodd.http.net.SocketHttpConnectionProvider.createHttpConnection(SocketHttpConnectionProvider.java:68)
    at jodd.http.HttpRequest.open(HttpRequest.java:665)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 20 more
---[cause]------------------------------------------------------------------------
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at jodd.http.net.SocketHttpConnectionProvider.createSSLSocket(SocketHttpConnectionProvider.java:153)
    at jodd.http.net.SocketHttpConnectionProvider.createHttpConnection(SocketHttpConnectionProvider.java:68)
    at jodd.http.HttpRequest.open(HttpRequest.java:665)
    at jodd.http.HttpRequest.open(HttpRequest.java:649)
    at jodd.http.HttpRequest._send(HttpRequest.java:747)
    at jodd.http.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:742)
    at jodd.JoddHttpTest.main(JoddHttpTest.java:56)
```

Comment: Post the complete stack trace. In your question.

Comment: According to the stack trace you are calling `startHandshake()`. Is this the real code?

Comment: @EJP Yes, why? I saw this in multiple examples, the same. And it worked? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer. From my experience, this:

```
sslSocket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket();
sslSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), connectionTimeout);
```

does not work (although you can see this solution everywhere!). Instead, I did the following: create a regular socket and then wrap it as SSL socket:

```
Socket sock = new Socket();
sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), connectionTimeout);
sslSocket = (SSLSocket)socketFactory.createSocket(sock, host, port, true);
```

where `socketFactory` is a `SSLSocketFactory` instance.